# Building Java libraries which depend on other libraries

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, lib

I'm trying to create a Java lib (jar) to use in a web app but I'm struggling a little with dependencies.

Say, if I wanted this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Shout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Shout().shout();
    }

    public void shout() {
        StringUtils.upperCase("help!");
    }

}
```

exposed as shout.jar.

The above depends on StringUtils but I don't want apache-commons.jar packaged in my shout.jar. Instead I'd like to find a way (if at all possible) to have Gradle or Maven automatically figure out what dependencies shout.jar needs in the web app that will use shout.jar.

I've tried to build a lib with Gradle (applying java-library plugin) and with Maven (with jar plugin) but still when I put my shout.jar as a Gradle dependency - it won't resolve StringUtils...

Is there anything in particular I need to do on the jar side for Gradle and Maven be happy with resolving a dependency of my jar?

**UPDATE with more details**

Sorry about being a bit vague. I'll try again with more details.

So, say I have my Shout class in a maven project. It's the same as above:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Shout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Shout().shout();
    }

    public void shout() {
        StringUtils.upperCase("help!");
    }

}
```

It has a pom file, with this bit inside (project tags omitted):

```
<groupId>michal</groupId>
<artifactId>shout</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Now if I run a Maven jar plugin I have a nice jar file called shout-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

If I create another project called UsingShout, this time Gradle with a Gradle config:

```
group 'michal'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'michal', name: 'shout', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

And I put my nice jar file inside lib dir like:

[(btw, the pom.xml is the same as above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bStmn.png)

And I try to do:

```
public class UsingShout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UsingShout().go();    
    }

    private void go() {
        new Shout().shout();
    }

}
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
```

I apologise if I'm not explaining myself very well.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to make this project a maven or gradle project, after that you'll be using this project as a maven/gradle dependency and not as JAR, in other projects

Comment: You'll need to show the POM or build file that didn't work.

Comment: I hope the above is a little bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

If you application is a maven project, you should add the following dependency into your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found an answer to my question...

My problem was that I was creating a JAR file and copying it to the lib folder and then instructing Gradle to get the JAR from a libs folder.

What I should have done is to do mvn install (on the Shout proj) and put the thing, say in my local repo, and then get Gradle to deal with it. Like so:

```
group 'michal'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'michal', name: 'shout', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: Sorry... I'm happy to edit it if you still think I should